# How to change the default font for a windows unicode locale / language

Tags: windows, unicode, fonts, locale

When I select a language from the language toolbar, windows automatically changes the input font to one with characters from that language. Is there are a way to change the default font to something else?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Surely it is changing the keyboard layout, not the font.

Comment: Hi, 

Is there a default font tied with keyboard layouts? Because when I change the keyboard layout it also changes the default input font. This is observed in notepad. Where does windows store the link to unicode ranges to specific fonts

Comment: How is this a programming question fit for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default UI font (which will affect everything). If the characters you are typing are supported by the default UI font, then a fallback font is selected, and you can't (officially) change what that is.

Answer (score 0):

One method used to work upto Windows 7, I'm not sure if it still works with Windows 8.

First, remove all fonts that support the given locale, and remember to copy the font files to somewhere rather than just deleting them.

Then, install the font you want to render the given locale. Open a document with characters from that range. In absence of the previous font font, Windows seems to fall back to the one available with characters defined in that range. Then install all the other fonts. The one Windows had already set does not get changed even when the "original" default font is available again.

Comment: This does not work for all cases. Say, the language Tamil by default uses `Nirmala UI` font which is a system font. I cannot uninstall or move this by any means, as this is protected.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS Have you found any method for this? I'm using it with Telugu, and it even displays wrong characters, which are not really in the language.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati In my case Tamil, I set the font ttf path value of Nirmala UI to latha font in the registry. So the default font for Tamil is now using Latha font's TTF file instead of original Nirmala UI. May be you can change it for Telugu.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS Can you tell me how to do that? And is it possible to set the path to multiple TTF files? I also type in Kannada and Hindi, so it'd be great if I can replace it with other fonts, based on the script.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/o3fdvs

Please refer this screenshot.

In the list, by default, Nirmala UI, Nirmala UI Bold and Nirmala UI Semilight are being used for display of Tamil fonts.

I changed Nirmala UI and Nirmala UI Semilight to `latha.ttf` and Nirmala UI Bold to `lathab.ttf`.

So that Nirmala UI fonts will be using Latha fonts' TTF files.

In the screenshot, you're seeing the default values now. The list will show all the fonts installed on your system with their respective ttf files names.