# How to change the default Gujarati Unicode font style (One of the Indian Language) in Windows 10?

Tags: unicode, fonts, registry

I am preparing for government exam and making my notes online on Evernote. In Past Evernote Legacy supports custom fonts and i was using **Hind Vadodara Font** for my Gujarati Language. But now in New version of Evernote, It supports only 6 Fonts and My Gujarati fonts changes completely (I don't liked it)

Now, Is there any way i can change default unicode font by changing registy value? I have read one answer here, and @Sarvap Praharanayuthan Sir have tell something, but i dont know how to do it (Screenshot uploaded by them is no longer available). I can't comment there, because i don't have sufficient privilage. so asking question here.

[Attaching this Screenshot for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oULvy.jpg)

**I tried to change default system font by changing registy value (**From Segoe UI to Hind Vadodara**). But it still doesn't change Gujarati Font Style.**

In this question, at the end you can find Sarvap Praharanayuthan sir's comment
[How to change the default font for a windows unicode locale / language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381309/how-to-change-the-default-font-for-a-windows-unicode-locale-language)